# Disable HTML Input "minimum" validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with the Angular.js two way data-binding.
I have an AJAX call from the server and i get all the datas wich I can present on the site, but there is a problem with the date input. I set a minimum value to it, but some dates (what i have from the data) is less than the minimum value.
So the HTML validation will transform my data to undefined.

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="item in products">
    <input type='date'
           ng-model='item.theDate'
           min='{{myMinDate}}'>
</div>
```

**myController.js**

```
function init() {
    productFactory.getSession().success(handleSuccess);

//the getSession function is in the productFactory file
};

var handleSuccess = function (data, status) {

    $scope.products = data.Products;
    $scope.myMinDate = data.minimumDate;
};
init();
```

So in other words if i don't use the min attribute for the input, everything works fine, but if is use it, then the `$scope.products.theDate` will be `undefined`

(Sorry for my grammar).

Comment: Sounds like a logic problem. If you declare a minimum and data doesn't meet it...what are you expecting?

Comment: @charlietfl i don't want to transform my data to undefined, but i still wanted to use the (native in chrome) datepicker which has the minimum attribute

Comment: still sounds like a logic problem if that date doesn't meet criteria

Comment: @charlietfl My bad. so we wanted to show the user the last modified date, which can be lesser then the minimum value, because they can set the min value elsewhere (Mindblowing I know).

Comment: so wouldn't those be 2 properties? User wouldn't be able to change `last-modified` I would think